# RegionDifference Fails at Two Simple Cubes

Tags: regions, mesh

Or, maybe, I just dont get it right.

I got two simple mesh cubes:

```
cube1Coordinates={{10,-10,10},{-10,-10,10},{10,-10,-10},{-10,-10,-10},{10,10,10},{10,10,-10},{-10,10,10},{-10,10,-10}};
cube1Cells={Polygon[{1,2,3}],Polygon[{3,2,4}],Polygon[{5,1,6}],Polygon[{6,1,3}],Polygon[{7,5,8}],Polygon[{8,5,6}],Polygon[{2,7,4}],Polygon[{4,7,8}],Polygon[{5,7,1}],Polygon[{1,7,2}],Polygon[{8,6,4}],Polygon[{4,6,3}]};

cube2Coordinates={{15,5,15},{5,5,15},{15,5,5},{5,5,5},{15,15,15},{15,15,5},{5,15,15},{5,15,5}};
cube2Cells={Polygon[{1,2,3}],Polygon[{3,2,4}],Polygon[{5,1,6}],Polygon[{6,1,3}],Polygon[{7,5,8}],Polygon[{8,5,6}],Polygon[{2,7,4}],Polygon[{4,7,8}],Polygon[{5,7,1}],Polygon[{1,7,2}],Polygon[{8,6,4}],Polygon[{4,6,3}]};

cube1=MeshRegion[cube1Coordinates, cube1Cells];
cube2=MeshRegion[cube2Coordinates,cube2Cells];

Show[cube1,HighlightMesh[cube2,2]]
```

But, `RegionDifference[cube1,cube2]`
[image: Two mesh cubes] does nothing!

What is the right way to substract one cube from another?

[image: BooleanRegion fails]

Comment: Change `MeshRegion` to `BoundaryMeshRegion` and try again.

Comment: @J.M. thank you sir, i'm such a nub ))))

Comment: I think this is a bug. It should do the equivalent of `m1 = MeshRegion[{{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 
     1}}, {Line[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}]}];
m2 = MeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
     1}}, {Line[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}]}];
RegionDifference[m1, m2]`

Answer (score 5):

The solution was embarrassingly obvious:

```
c1=BoundaryMeshRegion[cube1Coordinates, cube1Cells];
c2=BoundaryMeshRegion[cube2Coordinates,cube2Cells];

RegionDifference[c1,c2]
```

Comment: In brief: the problem was that you were trying to take the difference of two surfaces (`MeshRegion[]`) instead of two solids (`BoundaryMeshRegion[]`).

Comment: @J.M., and why should that not work? I understand what OP wanted, but I see not reason why `RegionDifference` should not have worked in some way. Either in analogy to the 2D example (or that is a bug also) and it would return a lower level difference.

Comment: @user21 I can't say exactly why, but I'll show a simpler example: `RegionDifference[DiscretizeRegion @ Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], DiscretizeRegion @ Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, 1]]` does nothing, but `RegionDifference[DiscretizeRegion @ Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1], 
 DiscretizeRegion @ Ball[{1, 0, 0}, 1]]` works well, and we again see the difference between surfaces vs. solids.